# How to write tests for Either<> from dartz package in flutter

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I am trying to write unit tests for a flutter app and I can't get this one test case to work correctly.

Here is the function returning `Future<Either<WeatherData, DataError>>`:

```dart
@override 
Future<Either<WeatherData, DataError>> fetchWeatherByCity({required String city}) async {
    try {
      var response = await apiService.fetchWeatherByCity(city: city);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Left(WeatherData.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)));
      } else {
        return Right(DataError(title: "Error", description: "Desc", code: 0, url: "NoUrl"));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      AppException exception = error as AppException;
      return Right(DataError(
          title: exception.title, description: exception.description, code: exception.code, url: exception.url));
    }
}
```

---

Here is the code where I am trying to write the unit test:

```dart
sut = WeatherRepositoryImpl(apiService: mockWeatherApiService);
test(
  "get weather by city DataError 1 - Error 404 ",
  () async {
    when(mockWeatherApiService.fetchWeatherByCity(city: "city"))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => Future.value(weatherRepoMockData.badResponse));
    final result = await sut.fetchWeatherByCity(city: "city");
    verify(mockWeatherApiService.fetchWeatherByCity(city: "city")).called(1);
    expect(result, isInstanceOf<DataError>);
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockWeatherApiService);
  },
);
```

When I run this specific test, I receive this error:

```
    Expected: <Instance of 'DataError'>
    Actual: Right<WeatherData, DataError>:<Right(Instance of 'DataError')>
    Which: is not an instance of 'DataError'
```

What I am not getting here? What should I be expecting from the function for the test to pass successfully?

Comment: can you include as code-snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are directly using the `result` which is actually a wrapper and has a type of `Either<WeatherData, DataError>`.

You need to unwrap the value using the `fold` method on the result and then expect accordingly, So in your code you can do something like this to make it work:

```
final result = await sut.fetchWeatherByCity(city: "city");

result.fold(
(left) => fail('test failed'), 
(right) {
  expect(result, isInstanceOf<DataError>);
});
verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockWeatherApiService);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either make the expected value a Right(), or extract the right side of the actual value.  Doing either of those will match, but as it is, you're comparing a wrapped value with an unwrapped value.